# Google Cloud Dataprep - How to replace a pattern in a string

Tags: google-cloud-dataprep

How can I replace a pattern in a string in one column with a value from another column in Cloud Dataprep?

To be precise, I have a column A with the same pattern in every string of the column, and I want to replace that pattern inside a string with corresponding value (when i say corresponding I mean the value in the same row) from another column.

Any idea?

Comment: Can you provide a sample of the data you have in mind?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should be able to do this in two steps:

1.- [Splitting the column](https://cloud.google.com/dataprep/docs/html/Split-Transform_57344651) (using the pattern in order to take it away)

2.- [Merging the column](https://cloud.google.com/dataprep/docs/html/Merge-Transform_57344642) (gathering the pieces together into the one desired column)